# Having mapper_parsing_exception when creating elasticsearch index all in Fields

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, dynamic, mapping, winston

I'm creating a winston-elasticsearch logger usin Kibana, where I need to save all what is happen in the app (request, apis, ...).I used this( https://github.com/vanthome/winston-elasticsearch)  I defined a json mapping template. Also a transformer.js file where I define a Transformer function to transform log data as provided by winston into a message structure which is more appropriate for indexing in ES.

then I use the winston-elasticsearch to create new Es instance:

```
exports.mappingTemplate = require('../../../index-template-mapping.json');
const TransportersElastic = new Elasticsearch({
  index: 'soapserver',
  level: 'info',
  indexPrefix: 'logs',
  transformer: transformer,
  ensureMappingTemplate: true,
  mappingTemplate: mappingTemplate,
  flushInterval: 2000,
  waitForActiveShards: 1,
  handleExceptions: false,...
```

But I keep getting Elasticsearch index error of type: 'mapper_parsing_exception' reasons like : failed to parse field [fields.result.status] of type [text]'

illegal_argument_exception' reason : 'failed to parse field [fields.rows.tmcode] of type [long]'
Here transformer.js:

```
exports.mappingTemplate = require('../../../index-template-mapping.json');
exports.transformer = (logData) => {
  const transformed = {};
  transformed['@timestamp'] = new Date().toISOString();
  transformed.source_host = os.hostname();
  transformed.message = logData.message;
  if (typeof transformed.message === 'object') {
    transformed.message = JSON.stringify(transformed.message);
```

I need help, suggestion how to resolve those error and succeed the Mapping.

Here the index-mapping-template.json

```
{
  "mapping": {
     "_doc": {
       "properties": {
         "@timestamp": {
           "type": "date"
           },
    "fields": {
      "ignore_malformed": true,
      "dynamic": "true",
      "properties": {}
    },
    "message": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "severity": {
      "type": "keyword"

       }
     }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you share the value of `fields.result.status` field for first few documents you are trying to index

Comment: Errors like: Elasticsearch index error { _index: 'soapserver',
  _type: '_doc',
  _id: 'ST2emmgB_PxjrK6Pmtdg',
  status: 400,
  error:
   { type: 'mapper_parsing_exception',
     reason:
      'failed to parse field [fields.config.wsdl_options.authType] of type [boolean]',
     caused_by:
      { type: 'illegal_argument_exception',
        reason:
         'Failed to parse value [WSSecurity] as only [true] or [false] are allowed.' } } }

Comment: illegal_argument_exception .reason:
         'Failed to parse value [WSSecurity] as only [true] or [false] are allowed.'

Comment: The reason for this error is that you are trying index a document having value of `WSSecurity` field other than allowed values for boolean type field. Means that value of `WSSecurity` in that document has a value other than `true` or `false`

Comment: I am using a dynamic Mapping so for example WSSecurity can be boolean or a string in some case also for other fiels , I need to the mapping doesn't generate errors related to type.That is why I use  "fields": {
      "ignore_malformed": true,
      "dynamic": "true",
      "properties": {}

Comment: Not all datatype support `ignore_malformed` parameter. [date](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/date.html#date-params) is the one that supports whereas [boolean](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/boolean.html#boolean-params) doesn't and hence the error.

Comment: OK, I deleted ignore_malformed , so do you have an idea , how can I force the fields to differnt level of sub fields without type restriction?

Comment: Have a look at [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html). You can force every fields to be of type `keyword` or `text`. Though it totally depends how you are going to query them.